# Running Protractor from Node-webkit

Tags: node.js, selenium, webdriver, protractor, node-webkit

Is is possible to run Protractor in any other way except using CLI?

Is there an API call which will simulate the command: '`protractor config file.js`'?

I would like to start a test through a `node-webkit` application, and even though I can connect directly to the ChromeDriver through the `directConnect` parameter, this is no use if I can't run protractor from inside the script.

Of course, this is in an environment where Node and Protractor aren't available from CLI... simulating a distribution environment where the user doesn't have to install additional apps apart from my `node-webkit` (hence the `node-webkit` usage).

Thank you in advance for any pointers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `protractor` command line script [boils down to](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/bin/protractor) invoking [lib/cli.js](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/cli.js) which mostly deals with parsing commmand-line arguments and then invokes [lib/launcher.js](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/launcher.js) to actually start protractor.

I don't think any special concessions have been made in these files to be directly invoked programmatically, but I don't see any particular hurdles either.